# TCP sockets with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, sockets, whois

I want to query a WHOIS server with PHP. This means that I have to TCP connect to Port 43 on the WHOIS server. Is there a way to do this with the ZEND Framework? I only found HTTP socket adapters.

I will do it with the native PHP socket functions if ZF does not provide wrapper classes.

Thank you
Lennart

Answer (score 1):

There is none. Your best bet is either plain php sockets, or you could check out [phpclasses.org](http://phpclasses.org) for already made whois classes.

Answer (score 0):

why not using [phpwhois](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpwhois/) for this?

It does not relate to zend framework, but this should be no problem.